# Evaluating RPG-formatted dice rolls with repeats in Clojure

Tags: clojure, dice

My target was to write a function that takes a String as input, interprets it as a series of dice rolls, evaluates it and returns a series of integers.

The input is in a form that is typical in table top RPGs, slightly extended:

- `1d20`; `d20`; `20` - Roll a single twenty sided die, result would be e.g. `12`
- `2d6 + 4` - Roll two six sided dice and add 4 to the sum, result would be e.g. `12` (5 [d6] + 3 [d6] + 4)
- `d20, d20`; `20,` (note the comma) - Roll two twenty sided dice and display the results separately, result would be e.g. `6 // 14`

I handled the parsing with [instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse). The function I am interested in feedback for, which you'll find below, is the one that then transforms a single "roll".

According to my specifications, I can add any number of commas (`,`) to a roll (a series of dice and constant modifiers). I opted to have those additional trailing commas parsed as being part of the preceding roll, syntactically, being added as `:repeat` flags to the end of the syntax tree. Because these rolls can be repeated, I had to pass functions instead of values, so the repeated rolls would actually yield different results. That means example arguments to this function can look like this:

`[#(d 4 12) #(+ 5) :repeat :repeat]` - which would correspond to `"4d12 + 5,,"`, where `d` is defined as follows:

```
(defn d
    ([count faces]
     (reduce + (map d (repeat count faces))))
    ([faces] (inc (rand-int faces))))
```

Without further ado:

```
(defn roll [& dice-info]
    (let [until-repeat (complement {:repeat true})
          [dice repeat] (split-with until-repeat dice-info)
          eval #(%)
          eval-dice #(map eval dice)
          eval-roll (fn [_] (apply + (eval-dice)))]
        (map eval-roll (cons :repeat repeat))))
```

I am particularly interested in how idiomatic this is, and whether the approach I've chosen is reasonable, but of course any input is welcome.

Here is the grammar text:

```
Series = Roll ( <','> Roll )*

Roll = <S?> ( QuickDie | ( Die ( <S?> Modifier)* ) ) <S?> Repeat*
Repeat = <',' S?>

Die = Integer? <'d'> Integer
QuickDie = Integer
Integer = #"([1-9][0-9]*|0)"

<Modifier> = ( Plus | Minus )
Plus = <'+'> <S?> Addend
Minus = <'-'> <S?> Addend
<Addend> = ( Integer | Die )

S = #"\s+"
```

And for completeness' sake, the whole code: [DiceRoll.clj](https://github.engineering.zhaw.ch/gist/vogelsam/06d36eae29d7cbebb2e0bef765cf274d) and [DiceRoll.eval.clj](https://github.engineering.zhaw.ch/gist/vogelsam/68673acd0c158fe463b275ce9e42ec95).

Comment: Can we see your Instaparse grammar text, please?

Comment: @Thumbnail sure, added it.